# How to declare a constant expression correctly?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, constants

I'm reading [The C++ Programming Language](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321563840) and trying to understand `Constants`. The book says this is valid:

```
const int dmv = 17; // dmv is a named constant
constexpr double max1 = 1.4∗square(dmv); // OK if square(17) is a constant expression
```

But when I do:

```
constexpr double square(double x)
{
    return x * x;
}

int main()
{ 
    const double x = 40.0;
    constexpr double result = 1.2 + square(x);
}
```

I got two errors:

1. *expression must have a constant value* (in `x`, if I replace it with a value for ex. `12.4` like `square(12.4)` the error disappears)
2. *function call must have a constant value in a constant expression* (in square method call.)

What is the reason of those errors ? What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prior to C++11, `constexpr` didn't exist, and compile-time arithmetic was only possible for integer types (more or less).

In that language, it made sense to make `const int` "variables" truly constant whenever possible, and not so for `const double`.

C++11 introduces `constexpr`, so that the special rule for `const T` variables is no longer necessary, but removing the rule would unnecessarily break existing code. C++11 also introduces compile-time floating-point arithmetic, but because `const double` variables were never treated as constant expressions before, and there is little benefit in changing that now, you need to explicitly say `constexpr`.

```
constexpr double square(double x)
{
  return x * x;
}

int main()
{ 
  constexpr double x = 40.0;
  constexpr double result = 1.2 + square(x);
}
```

Comment: I tried this before.Still I'm getting the second error: `function call must have a constant value in a constant expression`

Comment: @Selman22 Unfortunately, compilers have bugs and missing features. In your original code, the error you got was correct. In this code, the error you're getting is not correct, this code is valid. Your comment on icepack's answer says you're using VS2013, but [VS2013 doesn't claim to properly support `constexpr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx).

Comment: @Selman22 For whatever it's worth, the latest CTP partially implements `constexpr`, according to [this page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/12/02/c-11-14-core-language-features-in-vs-2013-and-the-nov-2013-ctp.aspx). You could see if you get better results in that.